# Issue in plotting 3d surface in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I have the following data, trying to plot a 3d surface.

```
data = [[10, 10, 0.84496124031007758],
    [10, 20, 0.87209302325581395],
    [10, 30, 0.88139534883720927],
    [20, 10, 0.86201550387596892],
    [20, 20, 0.87441860465116272],
    [20, 30, 0.88992248062015500],
    [30, 10, 0.87984496124031009],
    [30, 20, 0.89922480620155043],
    [30, 30, 0.92015503875968996]]

x, y, z = zip(*data)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
plt.show()
```

I am retrieving below error,

```
File "C:/Users/40227422/PycharmProjects/VideoDetection.py", line 29, in <module>
   ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
File "C:\Users\40227422\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site- 
packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 1496, in plot_surface
   if Z.ndim != 2:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three arguments of [`Axes3D.plot_surface`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) all need to be 2D arrays.

Replacing your call with the following will work:

```
ax.plot_surface(np.array(x).reshape(3,3), np.array(y).reshape(3,3), np.array(z).reshape(3,3), cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
```

Or with a list comprehension + destructuring:

```
ax.plot_surface(*[np.array(d).reshape(3,3) for d in zip(*data)], cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
```